# Strong Induction Proof of amounts of money

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

[image]

I am so confused about this kind of question which is referring to amounts of money. I know we should use strong induction to prove if we meet some questions asking you which amounts of money can be formed using $n$ dollar bills and $k$ dollar bills?

For the example above, the question is asking you determine which amounts of postage can be formed using $4$-cent and $5$-cent stamps. Such that we know $4,5,8,9,10,12,13,14,15, \ldots$ can be formed using just $4$-cent and $5$-cent. Why for basis are we just using $12-15$ instead of using $4-9$?

Another example on the book(*Discrete mathematics and its applications*), determine which amounts of postage can be formed using just $4$-cent and $11$-cent stamps?
[image]
Same here, we know that $4, 8, 11, 12, 15, 16, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, \ldots$ can be formed using $4$-cent and $11$-cent stamps. Why do we want to prove $P(n)$ is true for all $n \geq 30$? I don't understand how to find the $j$ and $k$ (The Second Principle of Mathematical Induction: if (i) $P(a)$ is true for the starting point $a \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, and
(ii) (for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$) if$ P(j)$ is true for any $j \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $a \leq j \leq k$, then $P(k+1)$ is true, then $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, n \geq a$)?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example above, the question is asking you determine which amounts of postage can be formed using $4$-cent and $5$-cent stamps. Such that we know $4,5,8,9,10,12,13,14,15, \ldots$ can be formed using just $4$ cent and $5$ cent. Why for basis are we just using $12-15$ instead of using $4-9$?

This problem appears to be taken from Kenneth H. Rosen's text *Discrete Mathematics and its Applications*.

You have misstated the question in the example.  What we need to prove is that every amount of postage of $12$ cents or more can be formed using just $4$-cent and $5$-cent stamps.

By showing that the four consecutive amounts $12$ cents, $13$ cents, $14$ cents, and $15$ cents can be formed using just $4$-cent and $5$-cent stamps, Rosen is providing a basis step for his strong induction argument that all amounts of $12$ cents or more can be formed using just $4$-cent and $5$-cent stamps.  He wants to show that for $n \geq 16$ that since $n - 4 = 4j + 5k$ for some positive integers $j$ and $k$, then $n = 4(j + 1) + 5k$.  Together with his demonstration that the amounts $12$ cents, $13$ cents, $14$ cents, and $15$ cents can be formed using only $4$-cent and $5$-cent stamps, this proves that all amounts of $12$ cents or more can be formed using just $4$-cent and $5$-cent stamps.

The reason Rosen starts at $12$ cents is that $12$ cents, $13$ cents, $14$ cents, and $15$ cents are the first four consecutive amounts that can be formed using only $4$-cent and $5$-cent stamps as it is not possible to form $11$ cents using only $4$-cent and $5$-cent stamps. Notice that the argument that if $n - 4 = 4j + 5k$ for some positive integers $j$ and $k$, then $n = 4(j + 1) + k$ cannot be applied when $n = 15$ since no such positive integers $j$ and $k$ exist for $n - 4 = 15 - 4 = 11$.

This is an example of the [Frobenius coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).  The English mathematician James Joseph Sylvester showed that the largest amount that cannot be formed using only $m$-cent and $n$-cent stamps with $\gcd(m, n) = 1$ is $mn - m - n$ cents.  The number $mn - m - n$ is called the Frobenius number.

In our case, $m = 4$ and $n = 5$, so the largest amount that cannot be formed using only $4$-cent and $5$-cent stamps is $4 \cdot 5 - 4 - 5 = 11$ cents.

> Same here, we know that $4, 8, 11, 12, 15, 16, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, \ldots$ can be formed using $4$-cent and $11$-cent stamps. Why do we want to prove $P(n)$ is true for all $n \geq 30$? I don't understand how to find the $j$ and $k$ (The Second Principle of Mathematical Induction: if (i) $P(a)$ is true for the starting point $a \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, and (ii) (for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$) if $P(j)$ is true for any $j \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $a \leq j \leq k$, then $P(k+1)$ is true, then $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, n \geq a$)?

We want to prove $P(n)$ holds for $n \geq 30$ since it is not possible to form $4 \cdot 11 - 4 - 11 = 29$ cents using only $4$-cent and $11$-cent stamps.

Observe that 
\begin{align*}
30 & = 2 \cdot 4 + 2 \cdot 11\\
31 & = (2 + 3) \cdot 4 + 1 \cdot 11\\
   & = 5 \cdot 4 + 1 \cdot 11\\
32 & = (5 + 3) \cdot 4 + 0 \cdot 11\\
   & = 8 \cdot 4 + 0 \cdot 11\\
33 & = (8 - 8) \cdot 4 + 3 \cdot 11\\
   & = 0 \cdot 4 + 3 \cdot 11\\
\end{align*}
Notice that in increasing from $n$ to $n + 1$, we either replace an $11$ by three $4$'s or we replace eight $4$'s with three $11$'s.

For $n \geq 30$, if

- $n = 4j + 11k$ and $k > 0$, then $n + 1 = 4(j + 3) + 11(k - 1)$
- $n = 4j + 11k$ and $k = 0$, then $j \geq 8$, so $n + 1 = 4(j - 8) + 11 \cdot 3$